# Using Native Library in Spring With JBOSS

Tags: java, spring, jboss, native, jnetpcap

In my application I'm using `Jnetpcap` native libraries. The native libraries are loaded using a `static` block in the `jar` itself.

When I'm loading the application freshly into `JBOSS` after start, it works fine.

Once I do any redeployment without restarting `JBOSS`, the application isn't able to register the library and throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Again, if I restart the JBOSS, it works fine.

JBoss Version: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA

Libraries are at classpath in Windows, and \usr\lib in linux.

Stack trace:

> 01:41:48,829 ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep]
>   (pool-6-thread-1) Encountered an error executing the step:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Ljava/lang/String;)J    at
>   com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.dlopen(Native Method)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.NativeLibrary.(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   com.slytechs.library.JNILibrary.register(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]    at
>   org.jnetpcap.Pcap.(Unknown Source)
>   [jnetpcap-1.4.r1425.jar:1.4.r1425]

Comment: could you please provide a full exception stack. and tell, where are your native libraries located? what is JBoss version you are using?

Comment: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA, 

In windows,
Libraries are located in classpath

In Linux,
Libraries are located in \usr\lib

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that the native library was previously loaded by the now defunct deployment and can't be loaded a second time.

The way to work around this issue with JBoss EAP (Wildfly) is to create a module that loads the native code.  The rest of your application (in a war or ear file) documents a dependency on the module and it will be loaded only once.